# Popup keyboard for emoji characters

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, kubuntu

How can I get a popup virtual keyboard with emoji characters while typing in a text field?

I'd prefer a solution where selecting characters inserts them directly into the text field (that is, bringing up the virtual keyboard doesn't steal focus).

I'm using Kubuntu, though an Ubuntu desktop solution might work as well (I can try).

Comment: There's a solution for GTK native apps in Gnome, but that doesn't help in KDE. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045915/how-to-insert-an-emoji-into-a-text-in-ubuntu-18-04